# Synchronize events in an Outlook calendar view

Tags: c#, .net, calendar, synchronization

In order to Synchronize events in an Outlook calendar Microsoft has provided the following documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/sync-calendar-view

To do that with C# .NET, they have provided the following Nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices-V2.0/

To play with that dll they have provided this basic sample: https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/tutorial/dotnet

Following that sample I have written the following code to get events:

```
    OutlookServicesClient client =
        new OutlookServicesClient(new Uri("https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0"),
            () => GetAccessToken(account));

    ExceptionDispatchInfo unauthorizedException = null;
    try
    {
        client.Context.SendingRequest2 += new EventHandler<SendingRequest2EventArgs>(
            (sender, e) => InsertXCustomHeaders(sender, e, account));

        client.Context.SendingRequest2 += new EventHandler<SendingRequest2EventArgs>(
            (sender, e) => InsertSyncCustomHeaders(sender, e));

        DateTime startDate = //Today
        DateTime endDate = // 2 years from now;

        IPagedCollection<IEvent> events = await client.Me.Calendars[calendarID].GetCalendarView(startDate, endDate).ExecuteAsync();                
        return events;
    }
    catch (WebException exception)
    {

    }
```

Source code of InsertXCustomHeaders and InsertSyncCustomHeaders used above:

```
private static void InsertXCustomHeaders(object sender, SendingRequest2EventArgs e, UserConnectedAccount connectedAccount)
{
    e.RequestMessage.SetHeader("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", connectedAccount.AccessToken));
    e.RequestMessage.SetHeader("UserAgent", GetUserAgent());
    e.RequestMessage.SetHeader("client-request-id", "Bearer " + GetClientRequestID());
    e.RequestMessage.SetHeader("return-client-request-id", "true");
}

private static void InsertSyncCustomHeaders(object sender, SendingRequest2EventArgs e)
{
    int initialSyncMaxPageSize = DynamicPropertyRepository.GetSystemPropertyInt("InitialSyncMaxPageSize", 100);
    e.RequestMessage.SetHeader("Prefer", "odata.track-changes");
    e.RequestMessage.SetHeader("Prefer", string.Format("odata.maxpagesize = {0}", initialSyncMaxPageSize));
}
```

I have no issue getting events with that code, i.e. I am getting events in 
IPagedCollection events variable above.

**Issue I am facing**:

I am unable to find how to get deltaToken, slipToken nextLink values as mentioned in the response at this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/sync-calendar-view with the above c# code.

Is Syncing of events even supported with C# .NET Nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices-V2.0/?

Is there any sample to perform https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/sync-calendar-view with https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices-V2.0/ library?

Answer (score 0):

First thing about that library: it isn't going to be maintained going forward, so keep in mind that new features and such won't get added to it. That's what you're seeing here, the library wasn't updated after sync support was added to the REST API.

Because of this, while you can force the headers into the request to enable sync behavior, the `IPagedCollection` doesn't expose anything that will help you do subsequent sync events, like `deltaToken`. For sync, you are going to want to move to something else. I've got a [sample](https://github.com/jasonjoh/dotnet-outlook-nosdk) that doesn't use any library. Instead it's all custom code, so you have complete control over requests and responses.

Comment: Can you at least write in your official documentation that "that" library is no longer supported and maintained?